# Resolving Type Conflict in Rust for Implementing Add<T> and Add<Wrap<U>> for a Generic Wrapper Type

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement std::ops::Add trait for wrapped type which is container of number.

```rust
struct Wrap<T>(T);
```

I wanna implement Add<Wrap<U>> for Wrap<T> when T implements Add<U>. so, I wrote following code.

```rust
impl<T, U> Add<Wrap<U>> for Wrap<T>
where
    T: Add<U>,
{
    type Output = Wrap<<T as Add<U>>::Output>;

    fn add(self, rhs: Wrap<U>) -> Self::Output {
        Wrap(self.0 + rhs.0)
    }
}
```

This is all going to be fine!

But, when I continue and tried to implement Add<U> for Wrap<T>. it fails.
(This operation is like "scalar multiplication")

```rust
impl<T, U> Add<U> for Wrap<T>
where
    T: Add<U>,
{
    type Output = Wrap<<T as Add<U>>::Output>;

    fn add(self, rhs: U) -> Self::Output {
        Wrap(self.0 + rhs)
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ec85c20cc376591913ee1d23cbdec57)

The error says that conflicting implementation of traits.

I know why this code is an error, but what can I do to solve this problem?
Or is there a general solution to this type of problem?

Comment: Until Rust gets either specialization or negative impls, I think this will be fundamentally impossible (and perhaps not possible even then).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What is the general compromise in this case?